# Adding a URL to my list makes my pandas data frame empty - RSS reader on Python

Tags: python, pandas, rss

This is my first python program and it reads RSS feeds (xml files), stores them in a pandas data frame and writes it to an excel file. it works as intended when there are 4 URLs but outputs an empty data frame when I add a 5th URL. Could this be a Pandas dataframe problem? or an excel problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


#url request to obtain the xml doc

urls=[
    'https://www.ccn-cert.cni.es/component/obrss/rss-ultimas-vulnerabilidades.feed',
    'https://feeds.english.ncsc.nl/news.rss',
    'https://www.cert.ssi.gouv.fr/feed/',
    'https://cert.be/en/rss',
   # 'https://www.cshub.com/rss/categories/attacks'  <--- ERROR/EMPTY DF IF I UNCOMMENT
    ]

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
    items = content.find_all('item')

title = []
date = []
link = []

for item in items:
    title.append(item.title.text)
    date.append(item.pubDate.text)
    link.append(item.link.text)

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Title': title, 'Date published':date, 'Link':link})
print(data_frame.to_string())


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('RSS.xlsx')
data_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mysheet')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['mysheet']
worksheet.set_column(1,1,130)
worksheet.set_column(2,2,40)
worksheet.set_column(3,3,120)
writer.save()
```

Comment: So your RSS.xlsx, has no rows?

Comment: Yes RSS.xlsx is empty if there are more than 4 URLs in the list. However when <5 in the list, RSS.xlsx will have about 194 items (rows)

Comment: No, it's your bug.  You fetch all of those URLs, but you throw away all of the results except the last one.  That loop overwrites `response`, `content`, and `items` each time.  When the loop exits, all you have is the last.  Thus, it's likely that the last URL simply has no items.  You probably want to do something like `items.extend( content.find_all('item') )`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks I will try that, however I have tried other URLs or even interchanged with the ones that do work so the URL has items. also I get what you mean when you say that all I have is the last, it does seem like it should be overwritten by the last URL every time but somehow when running, the excel file generated contains complete data of all the URLs, not just one.

Comment: Well, then, perhaps your indentation is wrong.  If the 7 lines following the first loop were actually IN the first loop, then it would work.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's it! thank you for the input Tim. The solution was a mix of the indentation, and also initializing the list before the first for loop.